# ScriptMethod not defined....VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I inherited a ASP.NET 2.0 VB website. I am getting errors related to AJAX:

```
  Imports System.Web.Script.Services
  <WebMethod()> _
  <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
```

One of the errors i get is:

```
  Type 'ScriptMethod' is not defined.
```

I downloaded the AJAX Extensions from Microsoft,and added a reference to System.Web.Extensoins.dll, but i still get the error. Where can i get the old AJAX libraries so i can build this site? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The imports you must have are these:

```
  Imports System.Web
  Imports System.Web.Services
  Imports System.Xml
  Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
  Imports System.Web.Script.Services
```

The dll's I have referenced are:

- System.Web.Extensions
- System.Web.Extensions.Design
- Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Which version of .Net are you referring to?